# Видеоплеер своими руками

Tags: flashvideo, flash, flash-player

Доброго времени суток! Решил заняться написанием видеоплеера (Flash CS5 AS3). Вытащил код с офф документации :

```
var nc:NetConnection = new NetConnection(); 
nc.connect(null);
var ns:NetStream = new NetStream(nc); 
ns.addEventListener(AsyncErrorEvent.ASYNC_ERROR, asyncErrorHandler); 
ns.play("vv1.mp4"); 
function asyncErrorHandler(event:AsyncErrorEvent):void 
{ 
    // ignore error 
}
var vid:Video = new Video(); 
vid.attachNetStream(ns); 
addChild(vid);
```

Работает всё прекрасно, но вот в чём проблема, не понятно куда именно вставляется "рамка с видео" которое воспроизводится в данный момент, сформулирую вопрос по другому, можно ли управлять положением видео на экране, украсить, обрисовать и т.д. и т.п. Если ли такой элемент, в который можно "направить(м.б. проецировать)" это видео и применить к нему возможности позиционирования? Ещё и нарисовал суть вопроса, дабы улучшить качество понимания)
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример был в классе наследнике Sprite, этот метод (addChild) оттуда, из его родителей. На этот Sprite навешать и нарисовать можно что угодно. Плюс нарисовать вручную нужный дизайн прямо в редакторе Flash cs.

Для задания координат есть свойства x, y.

Пробегите по документации к классу, там очень подробно расписаны многие важные вещи:
[flash.media Video](http://help.adobe.com/ru_RU/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/Video.html)

Если интересует програмирование (Flash CS больше дизайнерская штука), гораздо удобней будет Flash Builder, там есть даже язык разметки (MXML) похожий на html, он сильно облегчает написание интерфейсов (если цель - мобильные платформы, то гораздо лучше).

Comment: Спасибо, всё оказалось просто и интересно)

Comment: Нашёл как изменить положение и размеры, узнал как добавить в библиотеку компонент видео и перетащил его на рабочую область

var vid:Video   = new Video();
vid.width    = 500;
vid.height    = 400;
vid.x     = 0;
vid.y     = 0;

а вот как начать транслировать в него видео, так и не понял, подскажите код пожалуйста, думал, что если добавить этот компонент на рабочую область и убрать addChild(vid); , то видео автоматом будет направляться в него, но я ошибался, видео попросту не показывается, а звук идёт.

Comment: так на вашей картинке есть код с подключением видео потока (vid.attachNetStream(ns))

по ссылке к документации есть простенький пример - как проиграть FLV файл с того же сервера где находится флешка